# how to use the LightingColorFilter to make the image form dark to light

Tags: android, graphics, image-processing

I want to add light of the image, I want to use `LightingColorFilter`

```
LightingColorFilter lcf = new LightingColorFilter( mul, add); 
imageView.setColorFilter(lcf);
```

but I don't know how to adjust `mul, add`, can you give some link or code or parameters to adjust the light of the image?

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The integer values are colours (you may want to have a closer look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)
4 Bytes are used, one for alpha, one for red, one for green, one for blue range - every single from 0 to 255 (hex 0 to FF)

so the colour in hex looks like

```
0 x 00     00   00    00
    alpha  red  green blue
```

If you want to set for example red to zero, use

```
mul: 0xFF00FFFF
add: 0x00000000
```

If you want to force blue to be full-on, use

```
mul: 0xFFFFFFFF
add: 0x000000FF
```

Comment: I love those full explained and documented answers, but to add a hint to it : to lighten, use mul : 0xFFFFFFFF and add : 0x00222222 (22 for example)

Comment: @Darkendorf, how about to darken?

Comment: to darken, use a mul where R G and B are equal to the amount, 0xFF000000 would be darken to 0 aka black and 0xFF808080 would be a 50% black overlay

Answer (score 2):

```
Canvas canvas= new Canvas(my_bitmap); // create canvas from bitmap
Paint my_paint = new Paint(); // create Paint from bitmap

my_paint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x77777777, 0x77777777));//(mul, add)

canvas.drawBitmap(my_bitmap, 0, 0, my_paint );
```

1- now you can show my_bitmap

2- now my_bitmap have about 50% more light

3- you can change  (mul, add) to understand how work

4- also can use my_paint in other graphic method

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged since they don't provide insight into how a problem was solved. Please update your answer to include an explanation of *how* your code solves the OP's problem