# Bitmap with a color layer

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, layer, colorfilter

I have a ImageView where I put a Bitmap (left), sometimes I wanna see bitmap with a semitransparent blue layer (right). I try with a ColorFilter (LightingColorFilter and PorterDuffColorFilter) but I get a dark blue, how can I do this with ColorFilter or anything else?

[image]

Thanks.

EDIT (I tried this and other variants)

```
 //ColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color.wather, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
 ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(color.mul, color.wather);
 // mul = 0xFFFFFFFF and wather = 0x7000FFFF

 BitmapScaler scaler = new BitmapScaler();
 imagen.setImageBitmap(scaler.getScaled());
 imagen.setColorFilter(filter);
```

I tried diferents mul, add values and always get this:
[image]

Comment: can you post what have you tried?

Comment: ok it's something with your mul and wather values.. 
see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048941/how-to-use-the-lightingcolorfilter-to-make-the-image-form-dark-to-light

Comment: I already see it, I use 0xFFFFFFFF for mul to select all like example, but for add I wanna a semitransparent blue, I uses 0x7000FFFF but I do not get the right image but a dark blue and few transparent.

Comment: try 0x700000FF just for transparent blue 
see that for alpha FF is fully opaque while 00 is fully transparent
so you can even check 0x090000FF for add value

Comment: I try this and other, I always get a dark blue like show in top.

Comment: Maybe I can't get this with LightingColorFilter? Eclipse Description: Create a colorfilter that multiplies the RGB channels by one color, and then adds a second color, pinning the result for each component to [0..255]. ¡¡¡ The alpha components of the mul and add arguments are ignored. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already finds the mul, add values, I had a problem with color.xml because I used ID number instead the color RGB number, big mistake. Transparence (Alpha) are ignore but I can get the effect downing intensity of add value.

```
    int mul = 0xFFFFFF;
    int add = 0x005050;
filter = new LightingColorFilter(mul, add);
```

Thanks Elior for your help.