# How to set Button Background within arrayed colors?

Tags: android, button, user-interface

Why CustomButton results grey color? In R.color.blue and green and red are really red n blue and red. I'm trying to random colors of buttons within the colors red blue green from colors.xml.

```
public void CustomButton(int btnId) {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(btnId);

    int[] btnColor = { R.color.blue, R.color.green, R.color.red };
    Random random = new Random();
    int c = btnColor[random.nextInt(btnColor.length)];
    btn.setBackgroundColor(c);

}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to randomize the button colors I think this might help you --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185931/how-to-set-button-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

you should use

`getResources().getColor(yourcolorid)` to get the color

Small change in your code

Change this

```
 btn.setBackgroundColor(c);
```

to this

```
 btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(c));
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you. But I want to know why? Difference between your codes and my codes.?

Comment: @CingSianDal Because you are assigning the ID of Color generated by R, but the the value of color

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using custom colors, try removing the 'r':

```
public void CustomButton(int btnId) {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(btnId);

    int[] btnColor = {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
    Random random = new Random();
    int c = btnColor[random.nextInt(btnColor.length)];
    btn.setBackgroundColor(c);

}
```

This would use the built-in Android class [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

Comment: I don't want to use Color.BLUE Color.GREEN Color.ORANGE i'm trying to call colors from colors.xml by randomming. Please.. solve it.please